# How to re-order the Client Certificates

Tags: chromium-embedded, client-certificates, pki, cefsharp

In CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) support to display Client Certificate list dialog is not available, due to which I cannot display a certificate list using CefSharp browser while using PKI authentication. What CEF does support, is signing the user in by making use of the "first" certificate in the list. This works great if you only have a single certificate on your client.

The problem occurs when you have multiple valid certificates and the only certificate CEF uses is the first one. So is there a workaround for this?

Is there a way to "re-order" the client certificate list, to switch the certificate you need as the first one?

Comment: Eventually this will be resolved in `CEF` with https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/pull-requests/54/allow-cef-consumers-to-show-a-custom/diff

Comment: true but needed a workaround for the time being.

Comment: You can always compile your own build including that patch

Comment: Looks like the pull request (PR) link that @amaitland shared is declined but there is a new PR, https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/pull-requests/89/allow-cef-consumers-to-show-a-custom/diff   that should help with this. Once this PR is merged into CEF, will CefSharp automatically provide a client certificates dialog or a customization will be needed on CefSharp?